# CORS Issue same controller, one method is ok, other one is not

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angular-http

Very strange error I'm experiencing.

I have two methods in controller which are called by angular js http get event.

First one works fine, second one is throwing CORS error, not sure how is that possible since both of them are in same controller.

This is the error I'm getting: [image]

These are the calls I'm doing in angularjs:

```
 $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:52876/api/Admin/GetLoanInfo',
        method: "GET",
        params: { loanID: querystringParam }
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.LoanDetailsVM.LoanStatus = data.LoanStatus;
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    });

    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:52876/api/Admin/GetLoanCovenants',
        method: "GET",
        params: { loanID: querystringParam }
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

And the controller methods:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Admin/GetLoanInfo")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLoanInfo(int loanID)
{

        LoanApplication newApplication = null;
        newApplication = db.LoanApplications.FirstOrDefault(s => s.LoanId == loanID);
        return Ok(newApplication);
}


[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Admin/GetLoanCovenants")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetLoanCovenants(int loanID)
{
        LoanCovenant newCovenant = null;
        newCovenant = db.LoanCovenants.FirstOrDefault(s => s.LoanID == loanID);
        return Ok(newCovenant);
}
```

I'm able to hit both methods, I have breakpoints in both of the methods, but not sure why is complaining about CORS on the first one.

[image]

Comment: does it work when you open url directly in browser?

Comment: Do you have a full raw http request&response? Is CORS allowed in your back-end somehow? Have you cleared browser's cache?

Comment: I had an issue with the query, not sure why it was complaining about CORS. @charlietfi thanks for the tip which helped me to check the url in the browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Calling methods using CORS from a Web browser makes Web API being called first with an `OPTIONS` request (example [at the end of this article](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html)).

This way, the browser **knows** if it can call the requested API.

In your case, the call to your endpoint seems to be crashing, which means the HTTP 500 error does not contain any CORS headers.

This explains why the web browser complaning about CORS HTTP Header missing: `Reason: CORS Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`.

If you fix your method, then `HTTP OPTIONS` should be ok, and the CORS erros would go away.

Comment: To add on the method being broken. I had a controller that called a repo method by the same name. Which broke the controller. the CORS error will pop up on the browser while if you test the same method on Postman you'll get a 404. which told me that the method was wrong. Just be sure to test your method before trying on the browser, if you are controlling your API endpoints. especially when OPTIONS 200's and you still get a 404.